# How to update/refresh Viewer Node's image data via python?

Tags: python

I want to update/refresh the `Viewer Node` image data via python so that I can save the image.

Comment: You’ll want to turn on Auto Render as explained here https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/sidebar.html but I think that’s all you’ll need.

Comment: How to enable it via python?

Comment: bpy.data.screens["Compositing"].areas[3].spaces[0].use_auto_render, but you should iterate over areas to find the area of type "NODE_EDITOR" instead of using the magic number 3.

Comment: Aha! Using the next() function, we can find the first area of type "NODE_EDITOR": next(area for area in bpy.data.screens["Compositing"].areas if area.type == "NODE_EDITOR").spaces[0].use_auto_render

Comment: It doesn't works

Comment: That’s not a lot of info to go on.

Comment: It doesn't work when I enable 'use_auto_render' with python.

Comment: That’s the same amount of info, because that is exactly what and only what the code is supposed to be doing, as previously discussed. Please provide a precise error message as shown in the console.

Comment: It doesn't show any error but saves a blank image.

Comment: This problem is related to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274712/how-to-channel-pack-texture-in-python